# SVN failing when I try to check in changes..?

Tags: svn

I'm trying to update a WordPress plugin of mine, so I'm basically [following the steps here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/svn/) like I always have in the past without any issues.  For some reason it's not working for me this time.

The first thing I did was run "svn up" to get in sync with the remote repo.

That does it's thing and shows me I'm "At revision 973575" which [matches what I see for my remote repo](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/paypal-for-woocommerce/trunk/).

Then I made quite a few changes:  adding, modifying, and deleting some files.  At this point when I run "svn stat" I can see everything looks ready to go.

[image]

Then when I run 'svn ci -m "Version 1.1.5 Update"' it looks like it's working until the very end where I get an error:

> Transmitting file data .svn: E720003: Commit failed (details follow):
>   svn: E720003: Can't open
>   'D:\Websites\angelleye-paypal-library\solutions\wordpress\paypal-for-woocommerce-svn\.svn\tmp\svn-80124520':
>   The system cannot find the path specified.

[image]

Sure enough, if I try to find that /.svn/tmp/ directory it's not there at all, but I don't know when it would have been created or why it's not there now or how to fix this.

Any information on how I can get this working would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Cygwin?

Comment: Screen shots are not particularly helpful. Could you please copy/paste in the relevant text instead? Thanks.

Comment: @alroc, not that I am aware of.

Comment: @tripleee, I updated the original post with a text version of the error.

Comment: It's unclear to me if this is an error on the client side or on the server side.  At a guess, it's an error on the server side.

Comment: Me too.  I use Git the majority of the time, but for WordPress plugins I have to use SVN and I've never had this problem before.  Google isn't giving me much to go by either.

Comment: Seems like it must be a local problem because it's saying it can't find this local /.svn/tmp/svn-80124520.  again, though, I have no idea what that is or where it would have originally come from or why it's gone now.

Comment: That certainly looks like Cygwin. Perhaps your issue is something like described [here](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2010-04/msg01065.html)?

Comment: Ah, the command line tool I'm using is Git Bash.  I only use for SVN for updating my WordPress plugins, but I've always used this command line tool without any issue.

Comment: @derp, looks like it was just that simple.  :)  If you want to post as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: svn under Cygwin is always **BAD IDEA (tm)**, while you have native client. If you have Git, you can use SVN with git-svn or with SubGit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the `.svn/tmp` directory.

Why these disappear sometimes, no one seems to know. It could be some system cleaner utility trying to be helpful by getting rid of empty directories. It's possible they end up with the missing socks from the dryer. Your guess is as good as mine.